# C# Pass method with arguments as a parameter to Lazy<T>

Tags: c#, .net

Let's consider this code:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(Func<T> MyFunc)
{
    var NewLazyItem = new Lazy<T>(MyFunc);
    // do stuff
    // use the NewLazyItem
}
```

And let's say I have a method like this:

```
public int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

What I would like to achieve is to be able to pass the *Add* method  to the *DoSomething* method but with parameters along.
Ideally I could pass *Add*, *2* and *3* and when the *NewLazy* item gets used, *Add(2, 3)* gets called.

I tried various ideas, but I can't find a way to make it work.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't say `DoSomething(() => Add(2, 3))`?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I would suggest making your comment an answer before somebody else copies it and takes the credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, the simplest way is just to include the parameters as closures for a lambda expression:

```
var x = 2;
var y = 3;
DoSomething(() => Add(x, y));
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.. one of the perks of being up till 5am... Thanks!